# MySql Query Syntax error in update using case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to to update the second column value if first column is not null otherwise update fitst column. Below is the query that I have wriiten but this query giving me syntax error. Below is my query

```
UPDATE messages 
SET  CASE WHEN delete_one IS NULL THEN delete_one = 9600 ELSE delete_two = 9600  END 
WHERE
( message_to = 9600 AND message_from = 8625 ) 
OR 
( message_to = 8625 AND message_from = 9600);
```

Below is the syntax error that I am receiving after running this query

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case when delete_one IS NULL THEN delete_one = 9600 ' at line 3
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using the appropriate dbms tag! Mysql and sql server are not the same thing and use different sql dialects.

Comment: `update tablename set columnname = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CASE Expression has to be in the right side of SET:

```
UPDATE messages 
SET  delete_two = CASE WHEN delete_one IS NOT NULL THEN 9600  ELSE delete_two END,
delete_one = COALESCE(delete_one,9600) 
WHERE
( message_to = 9600 AND message_from = 8625 ) 
OR 
( message_to = 8625 AND message_from = 9600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning to a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE messages 
SET delete_one = COALESCE(delete_one, 9600),
    delete_two = CASE WHEN delete_one IS NULL THEN delete_two ELSE 9600 END 
WHERE
    (message_to = 9600 AND message_from = 8625 ) OR
    (message_to = 8625 AND message_from = 9600);
```